Probability with Combinations
I have a question that came up in a discussion in class today. I want to discuss the two different approaches/answers.  Here is the question:
"For a deck of 20 cards numbered 1-20:
A)  What is the probability of choosing the 3 and the 4 when drawing two cards?
I thought that the best way to approach this is to find the total combinations of 2 card draws: 20C2 = 190.  In, that 190, there is only 1 way to get a 3 and a 4 combination (2C2 = 1).  Thus, 1/190 is the probability.
My classmate only differed in that he said there were 2 ways to get a 3 and a 4 combination (2! = 2).  And his total probability was 2/190.
Which is the correct way of interpreting this question?  Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

You are correct. If you want to take into account also the order (i.e. considering $3,4$ different from $4,3$), then your denominator is $20*19 = 380$, and you get the same answer.

Thank you so much!!!
